# How to set and display default value into the existing value using widget.data in the Updating Task Page or other pages

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, widget, crud

I still new learner in flutter. I need help from you guys to help me solve the issues of how can I display or show back the existing data of the fields of color, date, startTime, endTime, remind and repeat using the widget.data (widget.color, widget.date, widget.startTime, widget.endTime, widget.remind and widget.repeat) in UpdatingtTaskPage that I passed from the Home Page. As I click the list view from HomePage to edit and redirect to UpdatingTaskPage, the fields that I mentioned earlier only will display the default values instead of existing values. (For example, the remind value from firebase is 15 minutes, it will show 5 minutes in the updating page as 5 minutes is default value that declared and set earlier). Anyone now how to solve it, please help me. Appreciate those help, thank you.

Images:

[image: HomePage]
[image: Firebase Data (remind value should be 15 minutes but it shows default value of 5 minutes, repeat is daily not none]
[image: UpdatingTaskPage is displaying default value instead of existing value]

**UpdatingTaskPage:**

```
class UpdatingTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id, title, note, date, startTime, endTime, repeat;
  final int color, remind;
  final bool isCompleted;

  const UpdatingTaskPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.note,
      required this.date,
      required this.startTime,
      required this.endTime,
      required this.repeat,
      required this.color,
      required this.remind,
      required this.isCompleted});

  @override
  State<UpdatingTaskPage> createState() => _UpdatingTaskPageState();
}

class _UpdatingTaskPageState extends State<UpdatingTaskPage> {
  static TaskController controller = Get.put(TaskController());
  final task = controller.tasks.length;

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController noteController = TextEditingController();

  late DateTime _selecteDate = DateTime.now();
  late String _startTime =
      DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  String _endTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a')
      .format(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 60)))
      .toString();
  int _selectedRemind = 5;
  List<int> remindList = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  String _selectedRepeat = 'None';
  List<String> repeatList = ['None', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'];
  int _selectedColor = 0;
  List<Color> colorList = [
    bluishClr,
    yellowClr,
    redClr,
    greenClr,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    titleController.text = widget.title;
    noteController.text = widget.note;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Update task!"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // this icon button is for the user to signout
                AuthController.instance.logout();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_rounded))
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Title
              InputField(
                title: 'Title',
                hint: 'Enter your title here...',
                controller: titleController,
              ),
              //Note
              InputField(
                title: 'Note',
                hint: 'Enter your note here...',
                controller: noteController,
              ),
              //Date
              InputField(
                title: 'Date',
                hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => _getDateFromUser(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //Date Range
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: InputField(
                      title: 'Start Time',
                      hint: _startTime,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: true),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: InputField(
                      title: 'End Time',
                      hint: _endTime,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: false),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //Remind
              InputField(
                title: 'Alert',
                hint: '$_selectedRemind minutes early',
                child: DropdownButton(
                  onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedRemind = int.parse(newVal!);
                    });
                  },
                  items: remindList
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: e.toString(),
                          child: Text('$e minutes'),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    size: 32,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  elevation: 3,
                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              //Repeat
              InputField(
                title: 'Repeat',
                hint: _selectedRepeat,
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedRepeat = value!;
                    });
                  },
                  value: widget.repeat,
                  items: repeatList
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: e,
                          child: Text(e),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    size: 32,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  elevation: 3,
                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              //Color
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text('Color'),
                    Row(
                      children: List.generate(
                        colorList.length,
                        (index) => Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, top: 8),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // Value(widget.color);
                                _selectedColor = index;
                              });
                            },
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: colorList[index],
                              child: widget.color == index
                                  ? null
                                  : index == _selectedColor
                                      ? const Icon(
                                          Icons.check,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        )
                                      : null,
                              // child: index == _selectedColor
                              //     ? const Icon(
                              //         Icons.check,
                              //         color: Colors.white,
                              //       )
                              //     : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: MyButton(
          label: 'Save',
          onTap: () {
            _validateData();
          }),
    );
  }

  _validateData() async {
    if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty && noteController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      print(1);
      _updateTaskToDb();
      Get.back();
    } else if (titleController.text.isEmpty || noteController.text.isEmpty) {
      print(2);

      Get.snackbar(
        'Required',
        'All fileds are required',
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        colorText: Colors.black,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('######## Error Here ! ########');
    }
  }

  _updateTaskToDb() async {
    await FirestoreDB.updateTask(
      taskModel: Task(
        id: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        title: titleController.text,
        note: noteController.text,
        isCompleted: false,
        date: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
        startTime: _startTime,
        endTime: _endTime,
        color: _selectedColor,
        remind: _selectedRemind,
        repeat: _selectedRepeat,
      ),
      documentId: widget.id,
    );
    Get.snackbar(
      'Updating',
      'Successfully update',
      backgroundColor: whiteClr,
      colorText: Colors.black,
    );
  }

  _getDateFromUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selecteDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (_pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        Value(widget.date);
        _selecteDate = _pickedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print('picked date empty !');
    }
  }

  _getTimeFromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    TimeOfDay? _pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (_pickedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (isStartTime) {
          _startTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_startTime);
        } else {
          _endTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_endTime);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archieve this by creating additional private member variables inside of your **State** object that will be initialized with the values of the **Widget**.

But you then use the variables of the state directly inside of the build method and you can also update them to new values.

For initialization you override the initState Method.

A Small example for your State class:

```
class _UpdatingTaskPageState extends State<UpdatingTaskPage> {
  //...

  late String _title;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _title = widget.title;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
                _title = "CHANGED";
              }),
          child: Text("change $_title")),
    );
  }
}
```

Following this pattern, change all of your accesses to **"widget.data"** from your **State** class and remove code like `titleController.text = widget.title;` from your build method.

Comment: Hello Niko, thank you for your help. Appreciating it.

Comment: No Problem! You can also mark the answer as accepted if it closes your question